# Vim shell commands (c flag) behaving differently in bash

Tags: bash, shell, vim, macvim

If I run this in the terminal (Mac OSX):

`vim dump.md -c 'vsplit poa.md' -c 'split one.md' -c ':wincmd h'`

It works great (creates three windows with those files).

If I have it as part of a bash script, there's a problem.  After doing what it's supposed to do, it leaves me with this in the vim status line:

```
1:dump.md  2:poa.md   3:one.md
1:dump.md  2:poa.md   3:one.md
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I have to press ENTER 6 times to clear the status line and return to editing (each ENTER outputs the above again).

Anyway around this?

Also, not sure if this is significant, but vim is aliased to mvim (MacVim).

**EDIT**

Here is the bash script, although I don't think it matters I've run the whole script separately before manually putting the `vim dump.md...` command it, and it works fine.

```
 13 
 12 #!/bin/bash
 11 
 10 cd ~/Dropbox/Journal/dumps/
  9 
  8 LAST=`ls -tAF | grep '/$' | head -1`
  7 NEW=dump-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%T")
  6 
  5 mkdir $NEW
  4 cd $NEW
  3 
  2 cp ../$LAST/poa.md ./poa.md
  1 
 14  vim dump.md -c 'vsplit poa.md' -c 'split one.md' -c ':wincmd h'
  1
```

Comment: please post the bash-script-part where you do this

Comment: as you say, it works from cmd-line for me as well. Try using `#!/bin/bash -x` as your shebang, that might reveal something. I'm on ubuntu btw...

Comment: debug output looks clean. thanks for the tip

Comment: I tried a modified version of your script (hard-coding the LAST and NEW env. vars to be 'foo' and 'bar') and it worked fine.  I am also using OS X (10.6.8).  Maybe there is something in your startup files that is trying to write to stdout.  Try adding `-u` to the `vim` line.

Comment: What's with the zany backwards line numbering? Anyway, if the first line ("13") is empty, take it out; the shebang `#!/bin/bash` needs to be the first line of the file.

Comment: haha @tripleee check out https://github.com/myusuf3/numbers.vim -- it's actually really helpful. in a 400 line file, instead of typing "352G" to jump down 10 lines you can type "10j". but yea i moved the shebang up a line and no luck.

Comment: @benjifisher tried the -u and no luck.  i think it might be a vim plugin.  i'm using the vim.spf13.com setup.  thanks for trying it on your system

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write `vim -u NONE `.  That should stop plugins and other startup files from running.  I also think it might be a plugin.

Comment: okay well that solves it.  it's a plugin.  thanks for your help debugging this.  gotta go cycle through 30 plugins or just forget about it

Answer (score 0):

At first:

```
ls -al
```

And see just your file is existed...If your file is `test` make sure vim doesn't cread such files:

```
.test OR test~ OR something like these
```

Then :

```
vim file
```

Do your changes...

After that close it by saying:

```
:wq!
```

Then try to open it again...The problem should be solved

**UPDATE**

try this one:

```
ls -a | grep swp
```

if there was a file like : .script.swp or something like these you should remove them...

Your problem would be solved...You should see if your script it existed with `.script....` and you should remove it...

If you can't find files start with **`.`** try to move all files(scripts) to another directory then work with them..and use `:q!` to quite and use `:wq!` to save and quite...

Comment: I faced the same problem...now I forgot what exactly I did...sorry...if I got answer I do tell you